# Should questions about solving a specific puzzle be allowed?

Tags: discussion

I'm talking about questions like:

> What is the solution to this cryptogram? FOO BAR BAZ

or

> What word goes here in this crossword with the clue "foo of the bar"

or

> How can I solve this [logic grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_puzzle#Logic_grid_puzzles) puzzle?

etc.

Should these be accepted as on-topic? I myself am hesitant to say yes, because they are extremely localized, and since they are so narrow they are unlikely to help future visitors. What do you think?

*(this is copied from my own post on [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14183/99336))*

Answer (score 3):

*note: this is not trying to be an official policy or anything of the sort; this is just my opinion*

It depends.

- If your puzzle is a programming puzzle or challenge, post it on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).
- If the puzzle **could have multiple answers** or the puzzle **is subjective or opinion-based**, do *not* post it here. This includes riddles, etc. The user shouldn't have to come back and say: "Hmm, that works, but it's not the right answer. That other one is right!"
- If the puzzle **is generic** or **can be trivially modified**, do *not* post it. For example, "Solve this hangman puzzle: P _ Z Z _ E" is bad because it's unlikely to help future visitors and it's way too narrow, but "What's a good strategy for guessing vowels in specific words in hangman?" (for example) is good.
- If the puzzle **is reasonably unique** and **could help others in the future**, post it here! For example, "How could I move three coins in this triangle to make it point the other direction?" (I just picked an example of a  fairly well-known puzzle for this, but there are probably much better examples out there)

*(this is copied from my own post on [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14384/99336))*

Comment: What about, for example, individual Sudoku puzzles?

Comment: Individual Sudoku puzzles do not help the future public & since so many solution providing sites already exist, it won't be helpful. However, if it can be somewhat generalized for a certain technique, it might be a different story.